# MongoDB sort with node-mongodb-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, node-mongodb-native

I want to sort the result of a Mongo query. From [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/) I found I could do it for example like this:

```
collection.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
```

As I dont want to sort by name, but by whatever is specified by request:

```
var query = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query;

var n = parseInt(query.limit);

var f = String(query.field);

var dir = query.direction;

collection.find().sort({f: dir}).limit(n)
```

Problem is, that it sortes by "f" and not whatever is value of variable f. How can I sort by whatever is stored in f ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query;
var n = parseInt(query.limit);
var f = String(query.field);
var dir = query.direction;
var sortObj = {};
sortObj[f] = dir;
collection.find().sort(sortObj).limit(n)
```

May be like this?